# How can the property of object in an inner ItemsControl bind to the property of an object in an outer ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, itemscontrol

The title might sound convoluted but bear with me.

I have Rooms which contain Occupants:

```
public class Room
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Occupants { get; set; }
    public bool AreOccupantsEditable { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here's an array of Rooms:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <x:Array x:Key="Rooms" Type="local:Room">
        <local:Room Name="Happy Room" AreOccupantsEditable="True">
            <local:Room.Occupants>
                <local:Person Name="Mindy" />
            </local:Room.Occupants>
        </local:Room>
        <local:Room Name="Sad Room" AreOccupantsEditable="True">
            <local:Room.Occupants>
                <local:Person Name="Bob" />
                <local:Person Name="Jane" />
            </local:Room.Occupants>
        </local:Room>
        <local:Room Name="Kill Room" AreOccupantsEditable="False">
            <local:Room.Occupants>
                <local:Person Name="Mork" />
                <local:Person Name="Dave" />
                <local:Person Name="Ryan" />
            </local:Room.Occupants>
        </local:Room>
    </x:Array>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Here is an ItemsControl in an ItemsControl, to display rooms and their occupants:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Rooms}}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <!-- room name -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Occupants}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- occupant name -->
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="20,0,0,0" IsEnabled="{Binding ???}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Without Person having a reference to Room, how can I bind the IsEnabled property of the TextBox to the AreOccupantsEditable property of the Room a Person is in?

If it helps, here's an example project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4220513/ItemsControl-Binding.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743599.aspx) to access the outer `DataContext` :

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DataContext.AreOccupantsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
```

Comment: I was playing with RelativeSource and AncestorType but I couldn't get it working.  I'll give this a go tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use IsEnabled property of itemControl of Occupants to disable whole itemControl

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Occupants}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=AreOccupantsEditable}">
```